# Find equilibrium points and stable/unstable manifolds of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the planar system $$\dot{x} = 2x-y-\frac{2x^3+2xy^2-xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
 \dot{y} = 2y+x-\frac{2x^2y+2y^3+x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$  which in polar coordinates is given by 
$$\ \dot{r}=2r(1-r) \\ \dot{\theta}=2sin^2(\theta/2)$$

1. Find all equilibrium points of this system and determine their stability properties. Are equilibria asymptotically stable? $\\$ 
   Letting $r=0 (x=y=0)$ could make the system have equilibrium but then the system would blow up due to denominator ${\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$ .$\\$ 
   So is $r=1,\theta =0$ (x=1,y=0) the only equilibrium point? $\\$
2. What are stable and unstable manifolds of the equilibria?

Comment: There is no blow up at $r=0$, as the numerator goes to zero in the 3rd power. $(0,0)$ is a valid stationary point, but you might get problems with Jacobian-based methods.

Comment: So then equilibrium points are (0,0) and (1,0). To find their stability, do we evaluate the Jacobian (which is tedius to differentiate) or is there easier way through polar coordinates?

Comment: For $(r,θ)=(1,0)$ you can stay in polar coordinates and compute the Jacobian with these coordinates, which will be diagonal. You get a contraction in $r$ direction and semi-stable behavior in $θ$ direction. Close to $r=0$ the angle is not that important, the main expansive behavior can be read off of the radial equation.

Comment: Evaluating the Jacobian for $(r,\theta)$, I got D(0,0) = {{2,0},{0,0}} and D(1,0) = {{-2,0},{0,0}}. Intuitively I see contraction in r direction for D(1,0) but I don't see how -2 for r will cause it. I am used to trace and determinant of Jacobian in x,y to determine stability. But how do we determine using $r,\theta$ ? And what is semi-stable behavior in $\theta$ direction?

Comment: $θ$ always has a non-negative derivative, it is increasing left and right of the stationary point. So on one side it has stable behavior, on the other unstable. You need to apply the methods for rank-deficient Jacobians. At $(0,0)$ all the values of $θ$ are valid, it is a singularity of the polar coordinates. Better use $r$ or $r^2$ as Lyapunov function, that argument is easier here.